# Prove that N(T)=0 and R(S)=U

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T:U \to V$; $S:V \to U$ and $ST:U \to U$. Prove that $N(T)=\{0\}$ and $R(S)=U$.

My professor gave us a fact at some point that if $ST=ID(U)$ we have S is surjective and T is injective. I am not sure how to prove this, and I think this is vital to answer this question.

My attempt: 
Given ST=ID(U), we have S is surjective and T is injective. 
Therefore, N(T)={0}.

Comment: Isn't the range of $T$ contained in $V?$ Why do we have $R(T)=U?$

Comment: Is it given in your question that $ST : U \to U$ is the identity transformation?